# Open Delta effect of disconnected leg

Tags: transformer

[image: Example Open Delta B primary open]

Wondering the effects on secondary if the B leg on an open delta open circuits. Say for example the primary line to line voltages are 260VAC normally from the source.
Lets take the PT ratio as 2.4/1

My thoughts are the secondary connection line to line voltages would then become (260 / 2.4) * (1/2), since the primary is essentially just transforming line to line across both primary elements, with the secondaries splitting this line to line voltage.

The other thing I was not certain of is what happens if the scenario is swapped (B leg secondary disconnected). Would the secondary voltages change any in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the healthy bank, the phase-to-phase voltages (e.g. a-b, b-c, and c-a) on the secondary are equal to those on the primary divided by the turns ratio, 2.4.

If you open the primary side B connection you are just applying A-C to the primary (single-phasing). Secondary a-c will equal this divided by turn ratio, 2.4.

The a-b and c-b voltages on secondary will be 50% of that value (neglecting loading effects).

Here is the normal open-delta connection diagram and resulting phasing diagram:

[image]
[image]

If you disconnect the B-phase connection on high-side you are effectively single-phasing the bank with this result.  Vab and Vbc have the same phase position and are 50% of normal magnitude.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So lets assume load is also in an open delta configuration, say one load from Vab, and one load across Vbc both identical. If B phase is opened on secondary, I would assume that each load would then see 108V / 2, due to Vac still having 108V, and it being voltage divided evenly across both loads. Is this correct? They would take on Vac or Vca phase angle correct?

Comment: That would be correct if the loads were identical.  It will just be a voltage divider across the two loaded which are now in series.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming constant, balanced loads... If A, B, and C are 120 deg out of phase with each other and 260V-LL, then the secondary phases will be 108V-LL. Opening B on the primary will not change the relative phasing or magnitude on A and C; however, you essentially have the same effect as a two single-phase transformers connected in series between A and C. The Secondary output A'-C' will be 108V, and the center tap will have lost its phase reference and A'-B', B'-C' will be 54V as you stated. The current draw on primary phases A and C will increase to compensate for the lost current from phase B.

Opening the secondary lead for phase B' with the primary connected will restore the phase reference for secondary phase B'. A'-C' remains 108V, but A'-B' and B'-C' revert to 108V.